# How can I use one source file in multiple web services projects?

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcf-client

I have the need to create two web services.  They do the same thing, but one has web references to "testing" services.  The other has reference to "live" services.

I'd like to create and maintain one set of source (.asmx) files using c# in Visual Studio 2010.

I've managed to create a solution which contains two web service projects.  I even managed to reference (using Add Link) the same set of source files in each project.

However, when I go to call the asmx file, the web service, the file's not found and I cannot figure a way to distinguish which service I am calling; the asmx files only exist in the common folder area, not actually within each project.

Answer (score 2):

If the testing and the live services use the same WSDL, then you do not need separate web references. Use a single reference, then set the Url property of the proxy class to point to the correct service.

Comment: Let me clarify... in VS2010 at least, you can 1) "add web reference" and 2) "add service reference".  Only on #1 does one have the "URL" property you mentioned.  #2 doesn't.  I'm using #2.  My understanding is that's the current way to do references.  #1 using the old .NET 2.0 methods for references.  I'm using 4.0.  Cannot seem to linebreak in the comments here... I've found since my post that I can set the "endpoint.address" value.  This might work, testing underway.  Thanks again!